# signInWithPopup vs linkWithPopup in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

What are the differences between signInWithPopup vs linkWithPopup in firebase? From the API reference, I can barely get anything useful regarding the differences.

Answer (score 1):

They are completely different operations.

`signInWithPopup` is for signing in an existing user through an authentication provider that can use popup windows to handle the interactions with the user. The alternative with `signInWithRedirect`, which does not use a popup.

`linkWithPopup` is for linking additional authentication providers to an existing Firebase auth account using a popup window. The alternative is linkWithRedirect, which does not use a popup.

I suggest reading through the documentation for signing in users ([Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin), [Facebook](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login)), and [linking additional accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking).